# Create CSV with columns selected by the user

Tags: c#, csv, design-patterns

I have a little design problem. Let's say I have a project that contains a large number of people. I want to allow the user to export those people to a `CSV` file with the information he chooses.
For example, He could choose Id, Name, Phone number and according to his choice I would create the file.
Of course, there is a simple of way doing it like `if(idCheckBox.Checked) getId();` etc.
I'm looking for something better. I don't want that for each new option I would like to add I would need to change the `UI` (e.g. New checkbox).
I thought of reading the possible options from a file, but that will only solved the `UI` problem. How would I know which values to get without using all those "if's" again?

Comment: How exactly "he could choose Id, Name, Phone number"? Knowing that the only questions left are how to save this data and how to use it during csv generation. `if` is perfectly fine, unless your columns are *dynamic*.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. I want to display the user all the options possible. From his choices I would create the file. He doesn't have to choose all parameters so if he doesn't want to export phone number it won't be shown in the file. But what if tomorrow I would like to add an option for dog's name? I don't want to change the UI, Explicitly check whether the dog's name option was chosen etc.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? You can't choose the right data structure to keep user selection? UI issue (how to organize selection)? File related issues (how to save only specific columns)? All of those (or none) can be the answer to your question. Could you provide information about how is it done now, what you want and where is difficult (for you) part?

Comment: You can define a base field and then a table of fields. Then each import/export uses your custom table to allow the selection and validate the data. You can also have your custom table read in the available and required field defs from a file. So as you add fields just update the mapping file.

Comment: Your best bet would be to decorate each of your exportable properties with an attribute, such as `[Exportable]`, then use reflection to reflect upon which properties have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a fancy design pattern for this task. However I understand you have identified a reason to change (added options in future). So you want to minimize amount of classes to be modified.

Your real problem is how to *decouple* CSV creation from the objects whose structure is going to change. You don't want your parsing logic to be affected whenever your Person class is changed.

In the following example the CSV object is truly decoupled from the objects it receives and parses. To achieve this, we are coding to an abstraction rather to an implementation. This way we are not even coupled to the Person object, but will welcome any objects that implement the AttributedObject interface. This dependency is being injected to our CSV parser.

I implemented this in PHP, but the idea is the same. C# is a static language, so fetching the attributes would be with a bit of change. You might use some kind of ArrayAccess interface.

```
interface AttributedObject {
    public function getAttribute($attribute);
}

class Person implements AttributedObject {

    protected $firstName;
    protected $lastName;
    protected $age;
    protected $IQ;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $age, $IQ)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->IQ = $IQ;
    }

    public function getAttribute($attribute)
    {
        if(property_exists($this, $attribute)) {
            return $this->$attribute;
        }
        throw new \Exception("Invalid attribute");
    }
}

class CSV {

    protected $attributedObject = null;
    protected $attributesToDisplay = null;
    protected $csvRepresentation = null;
    protected $delimiter = null;

    public function __construct(AttributedObject $attributedObject, array $attributesToDisplay, $delimiter = '|')
    {
        $this->attributedObject = $attributedObject;
        $this->attributesToDisplay = $attributesToDisplay;
        $this->delimiter = $delimiter;

        $this->generateCSV();
    }

    protected function generateCSV()
    {
        $tempCSV = null;

        foreach ($this->attributesToDisplay as $attribute) {
            $tempCSV[] = $this->attributedObject->getAttribute($attribute);
        }

        $this->csvRepresentation = $tempCSV;
    }

    public function storeCSV()
    {
        $file = fopen("tmp.csv", "w");
        fputcsv($file, $this->csvRepresentation, $this->delimiter);
    }
}

$person1 = new Person('John', 'Doe', 30, 0);
$csv = new CSV($person1, array('firstName', 'age', 'IQ'));
$csv->storeCSV();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a mapping set of fields based what fields the user is allowed to  select, and which fields are required. This data can be read from a file or database. Your import/export can be as flexible as needed.

[image]

Here is a conceivable data structure that could hold info for your import/export sets.

```
    public class FieldDefinition
    {
        public FieldDataTypeEnum DataType { get; set; }
        public string FieldName{get;set;}
        public int MaxSize { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public bool AllowNull { get; set; }
        public int FieldIndex { get; set; }
        public bool CompositeKey { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseImportSet
    {
        private List<FieldDefinition> FieldDefinitions { get; set; }

        protected virtual void PerformImportRecord(Fields selectedfields)
        {
           throw new ConfigurationException("Import set is not properly configured to import record.");
        }

        protected virtual void PerformExportRecord(Fields selectedfields)
        {
           throw new ConfigurationException("Export set is not properly configured to import record.");
        }    

        public LoadFieldDefinitionsFromFile(string filename)
        {
          //Implement reading from file
        }    
    }

    public class UserImportSet : BaseImportSet
    {
        public override void PerformImportRecord(Fields selectedfields)
        {
           //read in data one record at a time based on a loop in base class
        } 

       public override string PerformExportRecord(Fields selectedfields)
        {
           //read out data one record at a time based on a loop in base class
        } 
    }
```